# Google Thinks My Pages Are Duplicates, But They Are Not

Tags: google-search-console, canonical-url

Google is reporting that the pages I want to index are duplicates because I'm getting this message in my search console:

> Duplicate without user-selected canonical

Problem is they are not duplicates. They are jobs I'm trying to get in Google's job search. Is there a way to me to indicate to Google's search bot that all my job pages should be indexed?

The documentation they provide tells me to put a link tag in the header to allow me to specify the canonical pages (rel="canonical"), but if I understand it correctly that would just telling Google they are duplicates, right?

Any help is appreciated.

### EDIT

I was asked to show an example of two pages that are conflicting with each other.

Google thinks [this page](https://googlejobs.hyrell.com/UI/Views/Applicant/googlejobsPositionDetails.aspx?enc=l8RaKNPiYzAjliYk8VQ8ZnAR9kRLoM5m-i0cAKmP9B4=&tzi=Eastern%20Standard%20Time) is the same as [this one](https://googlejobs.hyrell.com/UI/Views/Applicant/googlejobsPositionDetails.aspx?enc=Iiw-1unNwz7r2L2qH985hpc3SKXnmOnVqYM0ZGOs16E=&tzi=Eastern%20Standard%20Time)

### EDIT #2

I added a bunch of og meta tags to the header, and added a section to the bottom of the page that pulls random jobs from the company and displays them at the bottom to add more unique content to the page. Still no telling me they are duplicates. I tried 2 new pages.

Comment: Google generally doesn't tell you what its duplicate 'off' so how have you determined the URL is not accessible by other means? such as `?query-strings` `https vs http` `with / or without /` `with www or without www` etc. Can you provide us a URL which has been marked duplicate, so I can check it for you?

Comment: @SimonHayter I updated my original post with the info you requested.

Comment: Do they render correctly using Google Fetch?

Comment: I just checked and they render fine. I also think they do have unique content, but it is a bit thin. I'd recommend adding a self referencing canonical tag for each URL. i.e. use the official URL for each job. This can eliminate other issues, but I don't think this one.

Comment: @SimonHayter I added a bunch of og meta tags to the header, and then added a "find more jobs" section at the bottom of the page that randomly displays 5 other jobs that company has open. So that should add some more unique content to the page, right? I'm all out of ideas, I mean it's a CMS system. Pages have set layouts, and data is pulled from the database to fill out the sections of the page dynamically. How does Google not have a way for people to indicate this? I'm nearly positive were not the first to do something like this haha.

Comment: @Vandel212 I'm having a similar issue. How did you end up solving this? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Checking the examples you provided, both pages are **nearly identical**, except for a paragraph of text and a title. You are incurring in what Google describes, as a thin  or duplicate content. They are so much alike that they are treated as a duplicate (even though they are not really).

You need to add more content to the page in order to make it more different between them two.

> If you have a single page accessible by multiple URLs, or different
>   pages with **similar** content (for example, a page with both a mobile and
>   a desktop version), Google sees these as duplicate versions of the
>   same page. Google will choose one URL as the canonical version and
>   crawl that, and all other URLs will be considered duplicate URLs and
>   crawled less often.

Source: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en